# Find elements in a collection beginning with some letter in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection in a mongo store where each element has a `name` attribute. I've sorted it alphabetically by doing

```
sort({'name': 1})
```

but now I would like to find only the elements beginning with some letter, say `t`. So a desired result might return:

```
[{name: tam}, {name: tom}, {name: tommy}]
```

How would I go about constructing a query like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/). In your case it will look like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  name: /^t/
});
```